# redefine method for every instance

Tags: c++, oop

```
class man {
  public:
    void do_something();
}

int main(){
  man Joe, Peter, Steve;
  Joe.do_something();
  Peter.do_something();
  Steve.do_something();

  return 0;
}
```

There is only one unique `man` called `Joe`. Same with `Peter` and `Steve`. And there is something unique about what they do. I may spawn hundreds of instances of `man` and I need to redefine `do_something()` function for each of them.

Two attempts I do not like:
1) `Joe` as a singleton class, that inherits from man.
2) passing a function pointer to `do_something()`.

I want to redefine `do_something()` function for each instance of `man`. Is it possible?

Comment: Create a sub class of Man for each person's "role" and initialize that instance which has it's own implementation to override do_something?

Comment: Yeah, make `void do_something` a member variable like `void(do_something*)(void)` and just assign it to a unique function for each instance i.e. `man Joe; Joe.do_something = [] () { /*function body*/ };` (Obisouly you can also pass the function to `man`s c'tor)

Answer (score 4):

The simplest thing to do is pass the action as a parameter to the constructor.

You could use a `std::function` or a lambda.
Or create another "action" class.

```
class Action
{
public:
    virtual ~Action();
    virtual void something() = 0;
};
```

If you inherit from this for the specifics of what you want, then each `man` can use the action in the `do_something` method.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way is to use `std::function` to customize the behavior:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class man {
  public:
    std::function<void()> something;
    void do_something() { something(); }
}

int main(){
  man Joe, Peter, Steve;
  Joe.something = [] () { std::cout << "Joe something."; };
  Joe.do_something();
  Peter.something = [] () { std::cout << "Peter something."; };
  Peter.do_something();
  Steve.something = [] () { std::cout << "Steve something."; };
  Steve.do_something();

  return 0;
}
```

If you want more functionality I suggest having an abstract class that's added to the `man` class that requires overriding `do_something()`. Then inheriting from that class for each different action.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Look at the strategy design pattern:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern

```
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class man {
public:
  man (std::string const& name) : name_(name) {}
  virtual void do_something() {
    std::cout << name_ << " does it" << std::endl;
  };
protected:
  std::string name_;
};

class Joe : public man{
public:
  Joe() : man("Joe") {}
};

class Fred : public man {
public:
  Fred() : man("Fred") {}
  virtual void do_something() override final {
    man::do_something();
    std::cout << "  ... but Fred can do way more" << std::endl;
  }
};

class ConcreteMan {
public:

  ConcreteMan(std::string const& name) : man_(nullptr) {
    if (name == "Joe")
      man_.reset(new Joe());
    else if (name == "Fred")
      man_.reset(new Fred());
    else
      std::cerr << "No such man " << name << std::endl;
  }
  void do_something() {
    if (man_ != nullptr) 
      man_->do_something();
    else 
      std::cerr << "No real man" << std::endl;
  }
private:
  std::unique_ptr<man> man_;
};

int main() {
  ConcreteMan joe("Joe"), fred("Fred"), donald("Donald");
  joe.do_something();
  fred.do_something();
  donald.do_something();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I didn't downvote. This is the obvious OO pattern to mention - but maybe put the details in the answer, not just a link?

Comment: Probably downvote because raw pointer, std::string has no member called equals(Java?), imo not convinced that passing a string instead of a Joe instance directly is better, and no explanation with just a link.

Comment: give me a sec i am still writing

Comment: isn't that a little bit too Java-ish than C++? Why dynamic allocation and boilerplate string parsing?

Comment: I really like the flexibility of the strategy pattern. The only place the different man would be known would be in the concrete class implementation not in the header. So only the cpp file would have all the `#include` entries. Really one of the most sensible patterns I can think of. Apart from Factory/Prototype, which is close but more of a structural pattern rather than a behavioural pattern. But then you get down voted :(

Comment: @KavehVahedipour I think too the strategy isn't the problem but the ConcreteMan implementation. It lose any advantage of the strategy if you have to add an if to the constructor every time you want to add something, and is it a very bug prone implementation

Comment: nice approach. `string` can be replaced with `enum` and `if else` with `switch case` to make it more efficient and less error prone I believe.

Comment: Love u back, friend. Not my invention though. Gamma et al Design Patterns

Comment: I also added donald, to demonstrate, what happens, when there is nothing behind the specific man. As long as you check for `nullptr`, you are fine.

Comment: Also modified slightly for default behaviour for `do_something()`

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:** Tag dispatching

You can just add a type and write the behaviour.

```
struct Joe{ void do(){std::cout << "drink";} };
struct Peter{ void do(){std::cout << "smoke";} };
struct Steve{ void do(){std::cout << "sleep";} };

class man {
  public:
   template<typename T>
   void do_something(){ T.do();}
}
```

since you have to call do_something() every time, you can consider saving the struct inside the man class, so you can rid of template:

```
struct man_detail{}
struct Joe : public man_detail{ void do(){std::cout << "drink";} };
struct Peter : public man_detail{ void do(){std::cout << "smoke";} };
struct Steve : public man_detail{ void do(){std::cout << "sleep";} };

class man{
public:
   man(man_detail md) : maninfo(md){}

   void do_something() { maninfo.do(); }

private:
   man_detail maninfo;
};
```

in any time your man_detail can evolve to an interface and add more methods.

**Solution 2:** Template specialization

your man class become a template, so man and man are to completely different types you can just provides a partial specialization.

```
struct Joe{};
struct Peter{};
struct Steve{};

template <typename T>
class man
{
   void do_something() {}
}

template <Joe> void man::do_something(){std::cout << "drink";}
template <Peter> void man::do_something(){std::cout << "smoke";}
template <> void man::do_something(){std::cout << "sleep";}
```

Comment: Making them separate types seems a bit inefficient, you end up missing out on being able to iterate them and things like compiler (or atleast single) assignment definition.

Comment: @It'scominghome it's enough providing an abstract class AbsMan and iterate through it

Comment: Basically `Joe` is it's own type. I would rather inherit from man and make it a singleton class (and I have an allergy for singleton classes)

Comment: @Moia It is but you get overhead, and can't generate new types at runtime.

Comment: @user3600124 you have to define in some way that `Joe` is not `Peter`. Tag dispatching and template method pattern are can delegate implementation. It's a "composition over inheritance" approach. Inheritance and singleton do the job too but I actually don't suggest that.

Comment: @It'scominghome you don't if you use `final` specifier for the template class.  What do you mean with can't generate new types at Runtime? If you mean he can't add `Bob` at Runtime, none tag, template or inheritance approach can't, but it isn't specified in the question.

Comment: `do_something()` cannot be defined at runtime either way

Comment: @user3600124 if you don't want to use a "type", put Joe etc. to an `enum People` and use the partial template specialization.